# Create a new Ruby CSV object with headers in a single csv.new() line

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to create a new CSV object with only the header row in it, but the headers are not set until I call `read()`:

```
[32] pry(main)> c = CSV.new("Keyword,Index,Page,Index in Page,Type,Title,URL", :headers => :first_row, :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true)
=> <#CSV io_type:StringIO encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true>
[33] pry(main)> c.headers
=> true
[34] pry(main)> c.read
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1>
[35] pry(main)> c.headers
=> ["Keyword", "Index", "Page", "Index in Page", "Type", "Title", "URL"]
```

Why is that? Why can't I get a properly working CSV object with my single `CSV.new` line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) will tell you it's treating the string as if it were the contents of a file (i.e. StringIO) so you still have to read the string just as you would any other IO source.

If you want to set the headers explicitly, you pass an array as the `:headers` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem persists:
<code>
    [49] pry(main)> c = CSV.new(nil, :headers => ["Keyword", "Index", "Page", "Index in Page", "Type", "Title", "URL"], :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true)
    => <#CSV io_type:NilClass encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true>
    [50] pry(main)> c.headers
    => true
    [51] pry(main)> c.read
    NoMethodError: private method `gets' called for nil:NilClass
[...]
    [52] pry(main)> c.headers
    => ["Keyword", "Index", "Page", "Index in Page", "Type", "Title", "URL"]

Comment: That's just the way it `new()` works. Whatever you pass it, file or string, you have to then `read()`. Maybe what you want is [`parse()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the 'string as file' thing, Sean. And as @the Tin Man noted - cool usage of :headers. This still doesn't solve the problem, though - c.headers is set to true after calling c = CSV.new(nil, :headers => ['col1', 'col2']). Strangely, in this case too only after issuing c.read (even though it fails on a NilObject!) c.headers is suddenly set correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the mess (new to this).

You were right - parse() solves this in one line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a way to do this in one call but you can easily remedy that with a  custom method of your own:

Given:

```
def new_csv(headers, data)
  csv = CSV.new(data, headers: headers, write_headers: true, return_headers: true)
  csv.read
  csv
end
```

You can call use it as:

```
csv = new_csv("Header 1, Header 2", "abc,def") 
=> <#CSV io_type:StringIO encoding:UTF-8 lineno:1 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:["abc", "def"]>

csv.headers
=> ["Header 1", "Header 2"]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping a more minimalistic (one liner) solution exists, but alas.